# I need a VBA code to count the number rows, which varies from ss to ss, return that number and copy and paste that row and all other columns

Tags: vba, variables, excel

I have vba question I have been trying to find the answer for for a long time. I have numerous spreadsheets from numerous clients that I run macro's on, I'm new to coding and have been able to mostly figure out what I need to do. My clients send us data monthly and every month the number of rows change. The columns don't change but the amount of data does. My previous macro's I have just chosen the entire column to copy and paste onto our companies template. This worked fine for must things but has created some really long code and macros take a long time. I would like to write a code that counts how many rows are in a certain column and then from there copies and pastes that however many rows it counted in each column. Only a few columns contain data in every row, so I need it to count the rows in one specific column and apply to that every column. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks
Tony

Hi Guys,
Still having issues with this, below I pasted the code I'm using if anyone can see why it won't run please help.

```
Windows("mmuworking2.xlsx").Activate
 Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\I53014\Desktop\QC DOCS\Sample_Data_Import_Template.xlsx"
 Windows("mmuworking2.xlsx").Activate
    Dim COL As Integer
    COL = Range("A:DB").Columns.Select
    **Range(Cells(2, COL), Cells(Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, COL)).Copy Destination:=Windows("Sample_Data_Import_Template.xlsx").Range("A2")**
    Range("A2").Paste
    Range("A5000").Formula = "='C:\Users\I53014\Desktop\[Import_Creator.xlsm]sheet1'!$B$2"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="Range (A5000)", _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```

I bolded where it keeps stopping.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should give you the last row containing data:

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

This will give you the last row in a specific column:

```
Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

here is an example of how I can copy every row in the first three columns of a worksheet

```
Sub Example()
    Dim LastRow As Long

    LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, 3)).Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Range("A1")
End Sub
```

You have to be careful as there are some caveats to both methods.

`ActiveSheet.UsedRange` may include cells that do not have any data if the cells were not cleaned up properly.

`Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` will only return the number of rows in the specified column.

`Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` will only return the number of rows in the first column.

**Edit** Added an example
**Edit2** Changed the example to be a bit more clear

For this example lets say we have this data
[image]

You could copy any other column down to the number of rows in column A using this method:

```
Sub Example()
    Dim Col as Integer
    Col = Columns("C:C").Column

    'This would copy all data from C1 to C5
    'Cells(1, Col) = Cell C1, because C1 is row 1 column 3
    Range(Cells(1, Col), Cells(Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, Col)).Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Range("A1")
End Sub
```

The end result would be this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Ripster I do have one question if I used "Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row" how do I get any future code I write to use that count to copy other columns.

Comment: Ok I think I got it now, but just want to make sure this is going to count Row "A" and copy whatever column I have "Row, 3)" in place of the 3

Comment: It will copy whatever column you specify. I used column 3 in my example. I updated the code in hopes that it would be a little more clear if a variable is used to get the column number.