# Delete row does not work

Tags: excel, row, vba

I am trying this code, that I have found on this side using excel 2016, but it does not work.  Want to put in number of row to start delete from.

```
Sub Sample()
   Dim Ret As Long
   Ret = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter a row number", Type:=1)
   If Ret = False Then Exit Sub
   With Mysheet1
       .Rows(Ret + 1 & ":" & .Rows.Count).Delete
   End With
End Sub
```

I have a problem here with this code

Comment: Can you tell us what does not work ? Can you enter a row number ?

Comment: Yes I can enter row number, but then it shows error on this line

Comment: .Rows(Ret + 1 & ":" & .Rows.Count).Delete

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: The error is   run time error "424"  Object required.   Not sure what object it is looking for

Comment: Did you define `Mysheet1`somewhere ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you have detailled a little ùore your issue, I think the problem is that you never declared what Mysheet1 is. Instead, what you can do is

```
With Worksheets("<YourSheetName>")
```

However, `Rows` does not work how you think it does. According to [the official documention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/office/ff821382.aspx), it has to be used on a specific `Range` object.[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842667/i-need-a-vba-code-to-count-the-number-rows-which-varies-from-ss-to-ss-return-t)tells us how to find the last row of your sheet. So , you can do :

```
With Worksheets("<YourSheetName>")
    .Range(Cells(Ret + 1, 1), Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1)).Delete
End With
```

Comment: It is working, but it is deleting a column and not the full rows, the column just move one on form the row number that I have put in.   I nee to delete the rows in full

Comment: Thank you will read the info that you have giving me.  But maby there is a way to do this

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to add an upvote and an accepted answer if you're satisfied with my answer !

Comment: Go it working {Sub test()
  Dim Ret As Long
    Ret = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter a row number", Type:=1)
    If Ret = False Then Exit Sub
    With Worksheets("UnixO")
        .Rows(Ret + 1 & ":" & .Rows.Count).Delete
   End With
End Sub
 }