# Unsure how to insert rows into sheet based on the number of visible cells in a filtered column

Tags: excel, vba

I am working of project for work where a macro will automatically generate credit notes and invoices. The problem that I am running into is how to write a code where excel will enter a number of rows that is equal to the total number of visible cells in a filtered column.

Right now the code (rather inelegantly) inserts 20 rows and then copies and pastes in the data from the filtered column. The problem is that sometimes the number of filtered cells in the column is greater than 20, which leads to different sections of the credit notes and invoices being overwritten.

Here's the section of the code that is causing all the issues.

```
Rows("30:30").Select
Selection.EntireRow.Resize(20).Insert Shift:=xlDown 

 ' InvoiceDates Macro 

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Application.Worksheets("Old Invoices")

ws.Range("b2:b1000").AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="Advertising Invoices", VisibleDropDown:=True

ws.Range("a2:a1000" & data_end_row_number).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Worksheets("creditnotes").Range("d30").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'invoice issue dates
ws.Range("c2:c1000" & data_end_row_number).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Worksheets("creditnotes").Range("h30").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'Invoice Month
ws.Range("c2:c1000" & data_end_row_number).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Worksheets("creditnotes").Range("d53").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'Total Amount
ws.Range("d2:d1000" & data_end_row_number).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Worksheets("creditnotes").Range("j53").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'VAT Amount
ws.Range("e2:e1000" & data_end_row_number).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Worksheets("creditnotes").Range("l53").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: `ws.Range("b2:b1000").SpecialCells(12).Rows.Count` will give you the amount of rows you'll need to add between the `Resize` brackets. Sidenotes: You should avoid `.Select` and are you sure you need to `Copy` and `Paste` these values? Why not just a `Value` transfer?

Answer (score -1):

So I think I would restructure your code a bit first. Currently, you are copying a range of nearly 1000 cells and pasting over, though I assume the number of required values is actually much smaller. So the first step is to determine the number of cells you want to copy. Once you have that, you'll be able to be more selective with which cells you copy and the number of rows you insert. Reference this topic for help with that : [I need a VBA code to count the number rows, which varies from ss to ss, return that number and copy and paste that row and all other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842667/i-need-a-vba-code-to-count-the-number-rows-which-varies-from-ss-to-ss-return-t/17843168)